# Why do distros(e.g. Arch) use BOTH initramfs and root={smth}?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, initramfs, initrd

I thought the goal of initramfs is to boot a root partition and chroot into it. But I can't understand why do distro developers use initramfs if there is ALWAYS a root={smth} flag.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought the goal of initramfs is to boot a root partition and chroot into it.

Not really, no.  From what I remember of Linux history, the predecessor of initramfs (initrd) was mounted and `/linuxrc` would run and then *exit* (see [obsolete root change mechanism](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/initrd.html#obsolete-root-change-mechanism)).  The kernel would then take responsibility of mounting root.  Later, the job of mounting root and pivoting into it was transferred over to initramfs and `/init` which does not exit.

This shows there is much more to initramfs than simply mount and chroot.

[Linus Torvalds stated two reasons for initramfs](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/initramfs.html):

- "make it easier for people to customize their initial system without
  having to muck with kernel code or even use a different boot sequence."
- "Many things are much more easily done in user space, because user space
  has protections, 'infinite stack', and in general a lot better
  infrastructure (ie easier to debug etc)."

---

> But I can't understand why do distro developers use initramfs if there is ALWAYS a root={smth} flag.

I would think of initramfs as a single compiled program.  Sure it's technically a file system containing scripts and binaries, but *typically* it doesn't contain (much) configuration.  Some parameters are best left to the user to modify at runtime rather than hard-coding them.

This lets you modify your system startup in your bootloader (eg: grub) without having to re-compile part of your system.  In grub that's as simple as pressing <kbd>e</kbd> on a menu entry.

Initramfs has access to kernel parameters through `/proc/cmdline`.  So even through `/root` was perhaps originally intended as a kernel configuration it lives on as an initramfs configuration.

Comment: So, should initramfs mount / by its own, or kernel will do it by itself using root= param, and leaving initramfs to chroot into it?

Comment: Initramfs does it usually by calling "pivot_root" - a user space command.  Initramfs typically reads the root= kernel parameter and obeys it. But some will allow other things as well.  Eg some support a "loopback=" allowing them to mount a file as /.  Also eg: some support setting an NFS share as /.

Comment: @Mr.Infinity A lot of initramfs are built around [busy box](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html). pivot_root can be found there.  As an example of parameters supported by initramfs see the documentation for ubuntu's [initramfs-tools](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html).

Comment: The kernel will not try to mount / if intrd= is specified, and will hand this job to initrd, right?

Comment: @Mr.Infinity So here we need to be careful.  `initrd` and `initramfs` are technically different things (second and third paragraphs under "[implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk#Implementation))".  They are specified using the same `initrd=` param.  Assuming you are using initramfs (containing /init) then the kernel will ignore `root=` and just run `/init`.  This never terminates.  The kernel does not mount root for you, initramfs does.

Comment: @Mr.Infinity However the (really) old "initrd" system is still there in the kernel source code.  If you were to use an actual initrd containing /linuxrc then, as the documentation says, /linuxrc would exit and the kernel would mount the root file system.  I should point out [this note](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fcadab740480e0e0e9fa9bd272acd409884d431a/init/do_mounts_initrd.c#L73) in source code: `using deprecated initrd support, will be removed in 2021.`